# Setting AutoGenerateColumns property from VS 2012

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Just now I got this strange problem and I wonder if there is something I miss in VS2012 to solve it. I'm working with MDI Windows Forms and I have this `dataGridView` for which I retrieve data from database and then set the `dataSource` property of the grid with the data from the database. But even though I use an old project as a scaffold for this one, now I get my `dataGridView` as designed in the VS2012 and next to it I get the data from the database as if it's part from my `dataGridView` design except the header columns are with the names of the columns from the database.

However I did a little reearch and find out that in fact this problem is easily solved by setting `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false. What I can't find is this property in the VS2012 designer. Now I'm using this :

```
        dgvClients.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvClients.DataSource = mainGridInfoList;
```

in the `load` event but I'd rather prefer to use the designer (if possible of course) and remove this line - `dgvClients.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` from my code. The problem is that I can't see property with that exact name for the `dataGridView` so I wonder - is the name changed? It would be kinda strange because I can still use it in my code, or there was never a way to do this from the IDE designer and it must be written in the source code explicitly?

P.S

It occurs that using the IDE designer is not very good decision for this particular problem (at least I think so) but here is a printscreen that can show you how to set this property from the VS2012 designer.

[image: AutoGenerateColumn]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found something in the documentation that might help with your question.

From [DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx):

> Note:
>
> Setting the DataSource in the Windows Forms Designer automatically
>   sets the AutoGenerateColumns property to false and generates code to
>   add and bind a column for each property in the data source. The code
>   that is generated at design-time is equivalent to the manually added
>   code shown in the following example. It is not the same as the
>   auto-generation of columns at run-time that occurs when the
>   AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true.

Comment: Thanks. I actually was wondering how exactly to set this from the IDE designer, but it seems that it's not the best way to accomplish this task, at least I find the information you provided very useful so just gonna add printscreen of where this property is located in VS2012 but I think to use the the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue because if the developer is not keeping an eye on it, the table will get messed up. I just resolved by setting the property in the class constructor to be sure it's kept whether the designer

```
    private SeniorsOnlineForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        seniorsOnlineGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    }rewrites its source.
```